# create layout in relative layout

Tags: android, layout

I need to create the `layout` like this but not getting perfect.

getting this

[image]

need this way

[image]

I am creating this using `RelativeLayout` and need to create in this only. I am able to create with sub layout using `Linearlayout` but can this possible without using any sub layout

this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15dp">
      <TextView android:text="Title" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
          android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:id="@+id/title_add_txt"/>
      <EditText android:hint="Address Title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/address_title" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_add_txt"/>
       <TextView android:text="Address" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
           android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:layout_below="@id/title_add_txt"
           android:id="@+id/address_txt"/>
       <EditText android:hint="Address" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/address" android:layout_below="@id/address_title" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/address_txt"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you do not use a Tablelayout for this scenario but if you have to use RelativeLayout, try playing with either android:paddingTop or android:paddingBottom for the TextView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layout_alignBaseline` should solve your problem - it aligns text baselines of the views on the same line:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_add_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5500ff00"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_add_txt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/title_add_txt"
        android:hint="Address Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_add_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#5500ff00"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/address_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/address_txt"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/address_txt"
        android:hint="Address" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've also added margin between TextViews. It looks like - I don't have your background image so EditTexts aren't aligned properly - if TextViews have the same width this won't be an issue:

[image: Device screen]

You can play with margins of EditText and TextViews to add necessary space between them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `TextView` and `EditText` aren't the same size. If you could make them the same size, they would probably align fine.

Providing the size of your views, yourbest bet is probably to stick with your sub `LinearLayouts`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test it, but see if this might help:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15dp">
    <TextView android:text="Title" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:id="@+id/title_add_txt"/>
    <EditText android:hint="Address Title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/address_title" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_add_txt"/>
    <TextView android:text="Address" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:layout_below="@id/address_title"
        android:id="@+id/address_txt"/>
    <EditText android:hint="Address" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/address" android:layout_alignTop="@id/address_txt" android:layout_alignLeft="@id/address_title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I've done is as follows: align `address_txt` below `address_title` (instead of below `title_add_txt`). I've also changed the alignment of `address` to align to the top of `address_txt` and to the left of `address_title` (this might probably be solved in other ways too).

Ad I said: I'm not able to verify it, but you can give it a try at least.

Comment: getting result near but it's work the textview was not center to the edittext they are on top means same level

Answer (score -1):

I would wrap the two related controls (label and corresponding input) in a `LinearLayout` and use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` setting on the `TextViews`.

somthing like this...

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="15dp">
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <TextView android:text="Title" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
          android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:id="@+id/title_add_txt"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
      <EditText android:hint="Address Title" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/address_title" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_add_txt"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
       <TextView android:text="Address" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp" android:padding="5dp"
           android:background="@drawable/tab_cyan" android:layout_below="@id/title_add_txt"
           android:id="@+id/address_txt"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
       <EditText android:hint="Address" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/address" android:layout_below="@id/address_title" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/address_txt"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nested layouts are discouraged by the platform authors - the deeper your hierarchy is the slower your application runs. [Optimizing Layout Hierarchies](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) contains example of significant speedup with flattened hierarchy.